# How to execute `Rollup` request using `Xrm.WebApi.execute` method in MS CRM using JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

There is a nice example how `Rollup` function could be called via MS CRM WebApi [here](http://butenko.pro/2017/05/09/how-to-call-rollup-of-activities-using-webapi/).

But it covers general access to CRM WebApi. Although in most recent versions new JS namespace `Xrm.WebApi` [was introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi). Which provides more straightforward way to access that endpoint.

Method `Xrm.WebApi.execute` should be able to execute `Rollup` request, as it is able to execute `WhoAmI`. But I'm struggling to figure out correct values of parameters to make this execution happen.

Here is my code:

```
var RollupRequest = function(entityType, id, query) {
  this.Target = { entityType: entityType, id: id };
  this.RollupType = "Related";
  this.Query = {
    Query: query
  };
};

RollupRequest.prototype.getMetadata = function() {
  return {
    boundParameter: null,
    parameterTypes: {
      Target: {
        typeName: "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference",
        structuralProperty: 5
      },
      RollupType: {
        typeName: "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RollupType",
        structuralProperty: 3
      },
      Query: {
        typeName: "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.FetchExpression",
        structuralProperty: 5
      }
    },
    operationType: 1, // This is a function. Use '0' for actions and '2' for CRUD
    operationName: "Rollup"
  };
};

var request = new RollupRequest(
  "contact",
  "0473FD41-C744-E911-A822-000D3A2AA2C5",
  "<fetch><entity name='activitypointer'></entity></fetch>"
);

Xrm.WebApi.execute(request).then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("Success: ", data);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("Failure: ", error);
  }
);
```

The code generates following URL: 
`/api/data/v9.0/Rollup(Target=@Target,RollupType=@RollupType,Query=@Query)?@Target={"@odata.id":"contacts(0473FD41-C744-E911-A822-000D3A2AA2C5)"}&@RollupType=&@Query={"Query":"<fetch><entity name='activitypointer'></entity></fetch>"}`

and the error: `"Expression expected at position 0 in ''."`

Which, seems to be, indicates that `RollupType` was not set correctly, because indeed in URL RollupType is missing.

I assume there are more than one potential error, because I'm using `FetchXML` as query expression. But meanwhile is it possible indicate what should be changed to generate proper URL at least for `RollupType` property?

Comment: I tried in CRM Rest Builder, that’s also incomplete.